# MongoDb returning only specific fields (phone numbers) in the form of an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to query and get all the phone numbers from one of my schema in the form of an array.

My schema is

```
 var doctorSchema = new Schema({
      profile: {
        fullname: String,
        gender: String,
        email: String,
        dob: Date,
        contact: 
        { mobile: String },
        } 
        });
```

Can someone help me how can I query only the contact.mobile and store all the numbers in an array ??

I tried $map but its not working.

Comment: `Doctor.find({}, 'contact.mobile' ...)` should return what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the **[`distinct()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.distinct)** method on the model using the dot notation to specify the embedded document field. This will query all the distinct values for the specified field across a single collection and returns the results in an array:

```
var callback = function (err, result) {
    if (err) { /* handle err */ };
    console.log('unique mobile numbers', result);
};

Doctor.distinct("profile.contact.mobile", callback);
```

or

```
var query = Doctor.distinct("profile.contact.mobile");
query.exec(callback);
```

In mongo shell, this will be equivalent to:

```
var mobilenumbers = db.doctors.distinct("profile.contact.mobile");
```

You can also use the **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method on the **[`promise`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise-then)** returned from the query as another way to get your results in an array:

```
var promise = Doctor.find({ }).select("profile.contact.mobile").exec();
promise.then(function (results) {
    var numbers = results.map(function (m) {
        return m.profile.contact.mobile;
    });
    console.log(numbers);
}).then(null, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The mongo shell equivalent operation uses the [`map()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.map/) cursor method and follows:

```
var mobilenumbers = db.doctors.find({}, {"profile.contact.mobile": 1})
                              .map(function (m){ 
                                   return m.profile.contact.mobile; 
                              });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/single-purpose-aggregation/#distinct)

```
db.doc.distinct('profile.contact.mobile')
```

For those sample data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56bef5f4d43b2f3239759505"), "profile" : { "fullname" : "DJ", "email" : "hhh.com", "contact" : { "mobile" : "123456" } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56bef605d43b2f3239759506"), "profile" : { "fullname" : "ad", "email" : "gg.com", "contact" : { "mobile" : "127886" } } }
```

result is

```
[ "123456", "127886" ]
```